# iOS -- get pointer from NSString containing address

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pointers

If I have a pointer to an object foo with address (say) 0x809b5c0, I can turn that into an NSString by calling

```
NSString* fooString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%p", foo].
```

This will give me the NSString @"0x809b5c0".

What is the easiest way to reverse the process?  That is, start with fooString, and get back my pointer to foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to an integer, then cast it to whatever type it's supposed to be...

```
NSUInteger myInt = [ myStr integerValue ];
char * ptr       = ( char * )myInt;
```

That said, I really don't understand why you will need this...

Comment: I was hoping there would be an easier way.  The integerValue part doesn't quite work as the string is hex, but writing one that does is not hard.

Answer (score 10):

In its completeness...

**To address-string**

```
NSString *foo = @"foo";
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", foo];
```

**And back**

```
NSString *fooAgain;
sscanf([address cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "%p", &fooAgain);
```

Comment: How can I use the same in LLDB while debugging ?

Comment: Easiest would be to just `po string` and copy what's returned and say `po 0x809b5c0` or whatever was returned.

Comment: But that will give me the description that mem addr holds. I want the pointer name\

Comment: If `string` is an NSString containing the memory adress: `po string` prints out the memory adress. `po <whatever was returned>` will print the object on that address.

Comment: This actually works, but be careful with memory management. It might be wise to mark `fooAgain` as `__unsafe_unretained`. When `fooAgain` goes out of scope, ARC will release it. If the pointer is pointing to `foo`, `sscanf` will not retain it. That means that `foo` will be a dangling pointer, because object was released when `fooAgain` went out of scope.

Comment: I couldn't agree more! Just answering questions.

Answer (score 4):

This snippet worked for me:

```
NSString *pointerString = @"0x809b5c0";
NSObject *object;
sscanf([pointerString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "%p", &object);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience its easier to convert the pointer's address to an NSInteger, like this:

```
MyObject *object=[[MyObject alloc]init];
//...
NSInteger adress=(NSInteger)object;
```

Now reverse:

```
MyObject *otherObject=(MyObject*)adress;
```

Now: object==otherObject

Comment: But if you want to print the name of the pointer itself, this wont be useful. Say in a complex hierarchy of `UIView` subclasses, you would like to know about a particlular UILabel , then you would be looking forward to the exact name of the label rather than another pointer to the same mem addr

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSMapTable instead:

```
MyClass* p = [[MyClass alloc]init];
NSMapTable* map = [NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory valueOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory];
[map setObject:whateverValue forKey:p];
// ...
for(MyClass* key in map) {
// ...
}
```