# Can I get the object by the Memory string

Tags: ios, objective-c

just like the title, I have saved the memory address as a string

```
MyClass *class = [[MyClass alloc] init];

NSString *pointerStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", class];
```

The "pointerStr" is the address string of class;

Now my question is Can I get Class By pointerStr? Thank you very much!

Another problem If the class is dealloc

how can I determine whether the object is effective

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756605/ios-get-pointer-from-nsstring-containing-address

Comment: you should use `NSValue`

Comment: @xlc How does that help?  Why wrap an object in another object?

Comment: @trojanfoe `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]` sometimes can be helpful. apple said `This method is useful if you want to add an object to a collection but don’t want the collection to create a strong reference to it.`

Comment: @xlc Memory management (strong/weak) hasn't been mentioned so it's not clear that the OP wants to store a weak reference.

Comment: @trojanfoe I believe for any purpose, store a pointer into a `NSValue` is always better to store it into a `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

This will work given iOS is a 32-bit system, however it's dangerous and shouldn't be done:

```
 MyClass *class = (MyClass *)[pointerStr intValue];
```

For 64-bit Mac, use:

```
 MyClass *class = (MyClass *)[pointerStr longLongValue];
```

But there must be a better way to store object pointers...

Comment: if it is a 64-bit system  How to get it thanks~ :)

Comment: That doesn't work with ARC.

Comment: @Jeremy I don't think it should be used, period.

Comment: got it as @user523234 said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756605/ios-get-pointer-from-nsstring-containing-address